# what does firebase_screen_class mean

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm now using Firebase Analytics to analyze the data about an app and I'm quite new to this field. In the bigquery, I found that under the *session_start* event field, there is a subfield called *firebase_screen_class* and there are some subclass like *FirstViewController*, *UIAlertController*, *preferencetableviewCotroller*, *PagescrollviewController*.
I tried to figure out what these mean and knew that these are relevant to the IOS app development. Is there anyone can help me better understand these terms or give me some helpful links for me to learn myself?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you're looking at the automatic screen_view event that firebase tracks for you.

firebase_screen_class is the name of the class that triggered it.
It will be something like "MyClassViewController" for iOS and "MyClassActivity" for Android.

You can find more info here.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=us-EN

Comment: Is the part where this refers to the "class that triggered it" been documented somewhere? 

Seems quite poorly named. Given that `firebase_screen` refers to the screen that is viewed and `firebase_screen_class` refers to the name of the class that triggered it.